# Arduino compatible Bluetooth Cat. 1 module

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm looking to add a Bluetooth module to an Arduino project that I'm working on that will take outdoor temperature measurements. I plan to have several measurement stations over distances of several 10s of metres which ultimately have to communicate wirelessly with a "master" station that logs the measurements from all the satellite stations. For reasons of energy economy, Bluetooth is the way to go, but because of the distances involved, it has to be BT Category 1 (100 mW, transmission up to 100 m). Does anyone know of such a module?

Thanks for any help that you can provide.